# bootstrap 3 row height is always 400px

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I am trying to get a Highcharts pie chart to display correctly.

```
<div id="chart">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div id="row-electric" class="row row-chart">
            <div id="divPieSubst" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>
            <div id="divPieFeedr" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-chart">
            <div id="divPieCycle" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>
            <div id="divPieRoute" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div id="divBarDays"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`row-chart` is something I tried to do with some CSS I found:

```css
<style>
    div.row-chart {
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Currently, I am struggling with the CCS, which I think is caused by bootstrap v3.3.7.

[image: screenshot]

Why is it always coming back as a tall rectangle?

I included the Highcharts tag, because this could be something that Highcharts is doing.

Comment: not sure base on what i see here but what i would suggest you to try is 'min-height':50px, 'max-height:auto' in your div.row-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharts API we can read:

> **height:** null, number, string
>
> ...
>
> By default (when null) the height is calculated from the offset height
> of the containing element, or 400 pixels if the containing element's
> height is 0. Defaults to null.

So yes - the height is set by the chart.

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

Answer (score 1):

What I understand that you want to resize the rectangles height?

have you took a look at this page ?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

The full snippet is needed I think what you posted is only a small part of it . I don't see any link to an external or internal bootstrap stylesheet .

another option is to resize the div tags with the css height property
so take a look at this link too
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

peace!